# Add data to existing json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So what i'm trying to achieve is creating a *`json`* flat file to store user info where i'm stuck is that i don't know how to add new nested objects that are empty and then save the json file and reload it.

what i have in my `*json*` file is this.

```
{
    "users" : {
        "test" : {

        },
        "test1" : {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add as many new objects as i want to it. So for example.

```
{
    "users" : {
        "test" : {

        },
        "test1" : {

        },
        "test2" : {

        },
        "test3" : {

        }
    }
}
```

**My server side Javascript**

```
    json.users.push = username;
    fs.writeFile("./storage.json", JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) , 'utf-8');
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./storage.json')];
    json = require("./storage.json");
```

With this code it does not write the file so when the require is done i end up with the same file and my json object ends up like this when i console.log it

```
{                                                                                                                                                    
    "users": {                                                                                                                                       
        "test": {},                                                                                                                                  
        "test1": {},                                                                                                                                 
        "push": "test2"                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Please do not recommend some external module to solve something has simple as this. Also if any one can point me to a in depth json documentation that gets straight to the point with what i'm try to do it would be appreciated

Comment: there is no such thing as JSON object. there's object, and there's JSON. it's the difference between a cake-recipe and a cake. there is no such thing cake-recipe-cake.

Comment: What do you think `json.users.push` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` to access a dynamic key on the object

```
json.users[username] = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Be careful naming your variable like that tho because `json` the way you're using it is not JSON. JSON is a string, not an object with keys.

See the below demo for distinction

```js
var json = '{"users":{"test1":{},"test2":{}}}';
var obj  = JSON.parse(json);
var newuser = 'test3';
obj.users[newuser] = {};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
//=> {"users":{"test1":{},"test2":{},"test3":{}}}
```

Comment: Straight to the point! You're awesome! Do you know where i can find a in depth documentation on manipulating json with JavaScript also do you have any clue why my fs.writefile is not working?

Comment: You never manipulate JSON directly. Always `var x = JSON.parse(yourJson)`, perform manipulations on `x`, then `JSON.stringify(x)` to rewrite the JSON.

Comment: I understand that what i am doing is non standard and that i must watch myself carefully to not screw up.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to use `fs.writeFile` in a synchronous way, maybe try `fs.writeFileSync`. If that doesn't help, you should ask a new question.

Comment: no i know that you use parse and stringify. i was not using manipulation in that sense.