# node.js fs.writeFile issue

Tags: node.js, debian

So this question extends this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940713/add-data-to-existing-json-object?noredirect=1#comment53707444_32940713) after figuring out what was happening i need to know if it's a bug I'm using node.js v4.1.0 on Debian and to solve my issue i was having with fs.writeFile i had to put the full path e.i /apps/json.json for it to actually save it where i wanted it to be but using ./json.json would save it to the /root instead of where my server.js file resided but how come when using require("./json.json") it works correctly and grabs the file relative to where the server.js is e.i /apps/server.js. Is this a know issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the current directory with the directory containing your script.

All `fs` APIs resolve paths relative to the current directory, which may be anything.

`require()`, by contrast, ignores the current directory entirely and resolves paths based on the directory containing the JS file.

Comment: Well isn't that a kick in the face. Any recommendations or should i just use the full path as i am now.

Comment: It depends what behavior you want.  You could set the current directory, or do `path.resolve(__dirname, './...')`

Comment: sorry i'm new to fs how would you set the current directory? and if i want to use path i need to require that right. Edit. just looked it up and the current directory is where you run the node from in the console so i get that part. so i think path is maybe my better bet.